# Airflow: How to schedule dag multiple times a day on specific times

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm trying to run an airflow dag at specific times on a day.

I'm aware that the airflow scheduler runs at the end of a period.
But this becoming a time scheduler nightmare and I need some guidance.

In essence I want to run the dag on `1:30`, `7:45` and say somewhere in the afternoon. Let's make it `14:00` so there is exactly 6h 15m between each run.
It's also important that it's UK time. It needs to switch with UK summer/winter time

This is what I came up with:

```py
dag_timezone = pendulum.timezone("Europe/London")
dt_now = datetime.now(tz=dag_timezone)
schedule_interval = timedelta(hours=6, minutes=15)
start_date = datetime(dt_now.year, dt_now.month, dt_now.day, 1, 30, 0, 0, dag_timezone) - schedule_interval
```

I expected it to immediately start running for today (1:30 & 7:45 run at least) since `catchup=True`

Alas, no success.
In the interface the start_date is `2020-07-30 6:30:00`
[image: start day hover]

It almost looks that the `schedule_interval` is added to the start_date instead of subtracted
I would expect `2020-07-30 01:30:00 - 6h15m => 2020-07-29 19:15:00 =UTC> 2020-07-29 18:15:00`

Also: Is there a debug mode for the scheduler to see the 'reasoning' ?

Answer (score 0):

In apache airflow when schedule your DAG then it is actually `start_data + schedule_interval`. For example, suppose I have passed `start_date=datetime(2020, 7, 30)` and my `schedule_interval=@daily` then actually my first task will run/start at 31st July not on 30 July